# I want to upgrade from 12.10 to 16.0.4 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, 12.10

I would like to upgrade (can do gradually to 13, 14, 15 etc) but none of the site are available.

Tried:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
sudo update-manager -d
```

Nothing works. I cannot even install aptitude. I am stuck for good?

Comment: It is much better (faster and more likely to succeed) to backup all the files that you really want to keep, and after that install a fresh Ubuntu system.

Comment: **To reopen voters:** Never mind. I voted to reopen by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @karel and strongly recommend making a backup of `/home` and doing a fresh install.  It may be possible to use the 16.04 Live iso to mount your existing hard drive and delete everything but `/home` on the drive, follwed by a [reinstall](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation) from using the Ubuntu installer on the iso (could be a usb stick of course).  But this is more error prone.  If you have an easy way of copying the user data to an external disk, do that.

Also, I would also copy the details of the user accounts that you wish to preserve, perhaps by copying the `/etc/passwd` itself and taking special note of the uid and gid values.  Then, to restore your files, make new accounts using `adduser` using the previous uid and gid values.  Then you can copy back the user data to the new user directories.  Even if you don't copy the `/etc/passwd` data, you can always get the uid and gid values from the copied `/home` file system itself using `ls -na`; uid and gid will be the 3rd and 4th column.  You can find the current values in `/etc/groups`.

Alternatively, you can simply make new accounts for your users, copy the old user data from your backup for each user to `/home/user`, and do a `chown -R user:group /home/user`.